# Reducing Javascript sub array to single array

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv, d3.js

I have a result of the following code

```
 d3.csv("../hello.csv", function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    var usable = data.map(function (d) {
        return {    
            description: d.description.split(" ")
        };
    });
    console.log(usable);
});
```

the console log of the usable  is  `[object, object, object]` when I expand it is

```
0:Object
  description: Array[3]
    0 : "A"
    1 : "B"
    2 : "C"

1:Object
  description: Array[3]
    0 : "D"
    1 : "E"
    2 : "FG"

2:Object
  description: Array[5]
    0 : "AD"
    1 : "BD"
    2 : "DC"
    4 : "HH"
```

What I need is single array as follows:

```
[A,B,C,D,E,FG,AD,BD,DC,HH]
```

with all elements reduced to single array rather than having multiple.

How can I achieve this? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You should be able to push (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp) the elements of one array to another or combine (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_array.asp) the two outside of D3 and use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not:

```
d3.csv("../hello.csv", function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    var all = [];
    data.map(function (d) {
        Array.prototype.push.apply(all, d.description.split(" "));
    });
    console.log(all);
});
```

Comment: This is exactly the suggestion I would give, make sure you mark this as the correct answer if it solved your problem. =)

Comment: @Jans: Great to hear, you can accept my answer if indeed it helped you :)

Answer (score 2):

You can flatten the array using `D3.merge()`. Assume these are your objects:

```
var obj1 = {description: [1,2,3]}
var obj2 = {description: [10,20,30,40]};
var obj3 = {description: [100,200,300,400,500]};

var array = [obj1, obj2, obj3]; // your array
```

So this produces the output you described:

```
console.log("array", array);
```

You can use `d3.merge(array)` to merge several arrays into one:

```
var flattened = d3.merge([obj1.description, obj2.description, obj3.description]);
console.log("flattened", flattened);
```

It will print:

```
flattened [1, 2, 3, 10, 20, 30, 40, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500]
```

See: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/helderdarocha/r84g43f2/)